# Renumbering auto-increment values in rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with an auto-incrementing primary key. Because I allow my data to be deleted, there are now numerous gaps in the primary keys. For example, if I have row 1, 2 and 3, and 2 gets deleted, I only have rows 1 and 3 left (meaning the number 2 is vacant and empty).

This has proven to give me problems now that I am attempted to conduct a full data migration. So I'm wondering if it's possible at all to simply re-index everything - i.e. run some kind of MySQL UPDATE query such that I update all the rows' primary keys into a smooth, running order.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: you should not typically do this at all.  you leave PK values alone, and then all FK references remain valid. Why does a gap matter? PK simply requires uniqueness.

Comment: It has to do with foreign keys as well. It's a long, long story :/

Comment: "This has proven to give me problems now that I am attempted to conduct a full data migration." Sounds like the problem is with your data migration, not with the PK values in your table(s).

Comment: Suffice to say that the old data was kept extremely poorly, and I've been forced to have to re-index everything in order to make any sense out of it. :/

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to create an empty clone of the table and copy all rows from your original one. That way all `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields are re-assigned.

1) Copy the table:

```
CREATE TABLE clone_table LIKE original_table;
```

2) Copy all rows, manually specifying all fields except your `AUTO_INCREMENT` one (`id`?) using the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO clone_table (field1, field2, fieldN) 
SELECT field1, field2, fieldN FROM original_table ORDER BY id;
```

3) Optionally, you can now delete old table and rename the clone:

```
DROP TABLE original_table;
RENAME TABLE clone_table TO original_table;
```

Comment: Good call. Imma go try that. Thanks

Comment: @Randy I'm assuming OP knows what he's doing. He never talked about FK in his question.

Comment: I do know what I'm doing but thanks for the concern guys. :)

Comment: you could probably just drop the PK column and forget about it altogether then.. no impact.